# Email form button that pulls the email address from the row that it's in

Tags: python, database, forms, flask, button

I currently have a MySQL database with column data: activity_no (AI, PK), email, date, activity_time, duration, sport_type, venue, postcode.

Using an SQL query I then display entries based on sport type to their relevant html pages in the form of a table (the email address is currently not included in the query).

I'm looking to add a "contact" button next to each table row in the table that will generate an email form to the address located within that row in the database.

Is this easier to achieve if the email address is included in the query and shown or can it be hidden?
Is this possible using python & Flask?

Thanks

I'm able to create an email form as I currently use one for my "contact us" page.
I'm just struggling with how to link it to the specified database cell information.

Answer (score 0):

I've included the email address in the SQL query.
embedded the email address in to the button.
used "mailto:{{a.email}}?" to generate email template.

Unable to hide the email address however this suits the MVP for my project.